# activity closes when home button pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-homebutton

I have 2 activities "A" and "B", "A" starts "B". I start activity "B" with startActivityForResult() method. When "B" is in foreground and home button is pressed app goes to background. And when I try to launch app again it starts with activity "A", not "B". Result for activity "B" is cancelled.
Why "B" is closed?
I thought that using launchModes in manifest can solve the problem but documentation says that I can't use singleTask and singleInstanse modes becouse the result will be cancelled and activity will not start.

How can I solve this?

PS
Thanks for answers, problem is solved. I tried to use finish() in onStop(), so when activity "B" is in foreground and home button is pressed, it finishes.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about launchModes for this. By default, B should be the top most Activity in your stack. Something else must be wrong. Do you see anything potentially suspicious on logcat?

Comment: can you paste you code of activity b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your activity B with an intent, using the method startActivity(Intent).

Your intent should be created with the arguments A.this and B.class, resulting in code looking somewhat like this:

Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);

A.this.startActivity(i);

Comment: In your case I can't get result from activity "B"